# Recursively creating columns with cross joining dictionary-like dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have one dataset with 7 variables and 5 indicators (df1):

```
   A   B   C   D  E   F  G R_1 R_2 R_3  R_4  R_5
0  4  16   5   7  1  12  9   B   C   D    F    A
1  8   4  10  14  4   5  9   B   E   A  NaN  NaN
```

Second key-value dataset showing cut-off value for each variable (df2):

```
  Variable  Value
0        A     11
1        B     15
2        C     22
3        D     25
4        E      3
5        F     14
6        G     15
```

Want to add another 5 columns R_new_1-R_new_5 on the condition:

if R_1 = B and (value of B, df1) 16>15 (from df2):

`df1['R_new_1'] = "C"` (from R_2)

`df1['R_new_2'] = "D"` (from R_3)

`df1['R_new_3'] = "F"` (from R_4)

`df1['R_new_4'] = "A"` (from R_5)

`df1['R_new_5'] = np.nan`

**Repeating above for the new R_2 value which is now stored in R_new_2**

```
  R_new_1 R_new_2 R_new_3 R_new_4  R_new_5
0       C       D       F       A      NaN
1       B       A     NaN     NaN      NaN
```

I have tried the below to automate the above:

```
var_list={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G'}
for col in var_list:
  df1[str(col) + "_val"] = df2[df2['Variable']==str(col)].iloc[0][1]

for col in var_list:
  if (df1[str(col) + "_val"] > df1[str(col)]):
    df1[str(col) + "_ind"] = "OK"  
  else:
    df1[str(col) + "_ind"] = "NOK"
```

The first run checks for R_1.
Unable to recursively **replace B with C in R_new_1** and **replace C with D in R_new_2** and **replace D with F in R_new_3** and **replace F with A in R_new_4** and **CONTINUE checking for R_new_2 and so on**

```
import pandas as pd
##dataframes constructers
#input
data1 = [{'A': 4, 'B': 16, 'C': 5, 'D': 7, 'E': 1, 'F': 12, 'G': 9, 'R_1':'B', 'R_2':'C', 'R_3':'D', 'R_4':'F', 'R_5':'A'},
        {'A': 8, 'B': 4, 'C': 10, 'D': 14, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 9, 'R_1':'B', 'R_2':'E', 'R_3':'A', 'R_4':np.nan, 'R_5':np.nan}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

#input
data2 = [['A', 11], ['B', 15], ['C', 22], ['D', 25], ['E', 3], ['F', 14], ['G', 15]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Variable', 'Value'])

#desired output
data3 = [{'A': 4, 'B': 16, 'C': 5, 'D': 7, 'E': 1, 'F': 12, 'G': 9, 'R_1':'B', 'R_2':'C', 'R_3':'D', 'R_4':'F', 'R_5':'A', 'R_new_1':'C', 'R_new_2':'D', 'R_new_3':'F', 'R_new_4':'A', 'R_new_5':np.nan},
        {'A': 8, 'B': 4, 'C': 10, 'D': 14, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'G': 9, 'R_1':'B', 'R_2':'E', 'R_3':'A', 'R_4':np.nan, 'R_5':np.nan, 'R_new_1':'B', 'R_new_2':'A', 'R_new_3':np.nan, 'R_new_4':np.nan, 'R_new_5':np.nan}]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```

Comment: Please provide your inputs as DataFrame constructors, and the explicit expected output. Images are not reproducible

Comment: @mozway Added the constructors, and the explicit expected output.

Comment: So if the value of an indicator is <= than its cutoff, then the indicator stays the same. If the value is > than the cutoff, then this indicator is replaced with `NaN`. After all indicators of the row are processed, shift everything left, so that all nans are only on the right (and not in the middle). Correct?

Comment: Then why are `F` and `A` left in the first row?

Comment: Your algorithm is unclear

Comment: @Vladimir - Sorry for the confusion, I have corrected the df2. Thanks for catching that!